# How to infer the type of a Return<T, E> value from a function return value in Rust?

Tags: rust

In Rust I can do the following:

```
let message: MessageFormat =
    serde_json::from_str(some_string_value.as_str()).unwrap();
// MessageFormat is a struct
```

Rust cannot use automatic type inference to infer the type from the function return value, because `serde` could return a structure of any type. So the type is explicitly specified using `MessageFormat`.

This code has an obvious problem. If the string does not match what is expected due to the structure of `MessageFormat`, then `unwrap` panics.

Removing the `unwrap` statement results in a type mismatch.

This could be fixed by changing the type from `MessageFormat` to something like `Result<MessageFormat, ???>`. I don't know how to do this, however it doesn't seem like a good solution, since the `Err` part of `Result` should be inferable.

Is there a way to write this inferring the error type, while specifying the deserialization type, which will obviously always be required.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the `_` [placeholder](https://doc.rust-lang.org/reference/types/inferred.html) to infer the type for the `Err` variant of `Result`:

```
let message: Result<MessageFormat, _> = serde_json::from_str(some_string_value.as_str());
```

or use the turbofish syntax:

```
let message = serde_json::from_str::<MessageFormat>(some_string_value.as_str());
```

Comment: Which function do I apply turbofish to?

Comment: @FreelanceConsultant, read one more line, there is an example of the function using the turbofish (hint it's `serde_json::from_str`).

Comment: To clarify the exact purpose of Turbofish here. Is the purpose of this to explicitly pass a type to a templated function. Excuse the C++ lingua franca. In C++ we would have a templated function and the compiler would instantiate one version of that function for each set of types which we use. Is that exactly what is happening here? We get a new version of `serde_json::from_str` for each type we pass to it using the Turbofish?

Comment: @FreelanceConsultant Yes, though in Rust you'd call it a generic function, not a templated function. And as you said correctly, [turbofish](https://turbo.fish/) syntax is used to explicitly provide a type for a generic type parameter.